# When I take a photo with my Android webview it saves it with 0B and doesn't upload

Tags: java, android, webview, save-image

So when I open my phone's file explorer it shows my image but it is 0B. It also doesn't upload the image. It seems like the app isn't writing to file properly and I can't seem to figure out why it does this. I have been struggling with this for a while now. If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it.
I am using SDK 29.
This is my Java code:

```
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){

    // Update message
    mUM = uploadMsg;

    try{


        // Create camera captured image file path and name

        ContentResolver resolver = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "IMG_"
                + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

        // Camera capture image intent
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");

        // Create file chooser intent
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

        // Set camera intent to file chooser
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

        // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:"+e,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (mUMA != null) {
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("Closing Activity")
                                .setMessage(String.format("Failed to create image.\r\n %s", ex))
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                                .show();
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request){
                request.grant(request.getResources());


            }
        });
```